# pushViewController and popToRootViewController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, dismiss, rootview, poptoviewcontroller

My application is using pushViewController to show the navigation controller modally

```
 [navigationController pushViewController:_viewController animated:YES];
```

Navigation Controller has done button

```
UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101]; 
[backButton addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[backButton setTitle:@"Done" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

UIBarButtonItem* backItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:backButton];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backItem;
[backItem release];
```

When done button is pressed I want that it should navigate back to main window

```
-(void) dismissView: (id)sender

{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//[self.navigationController popToViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

}
```

But when I press on done button nothing happens. Why is that?

Comment: Where are you putting that code that initializes the done button? Have you tried adding an NSLog statement inside the "dismissView:" selector to determine if it is actually being invoked?

Comment: How i can initialize the done button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please NSLog in your dissmissView

```
-(void) dismissView: (id)sender

{
   NSLog(@"Hii....");
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
//[self.navigationController popToViewController:_viewController animated:YES];

}
```

or debug the app with break point.

Answer (score 1):

```
UIButton* backButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:101];
```

im quite sure "101" is invalid

```
+ (id)buttonWithType:(UIButtonType)buttonType
```

you should use one of the following UIButtonType values

```
typedef enum {
    UIButtonTypeCustom = 0,
    UIButtonTypeRoundedRect,
    UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure,
    UIButtonTypeInfoLight,
    UIButtonTypeInfoDark,
    UIButtonTypeContactAdd,
} UIButtonType;
```

other than that test your code put some NSLog in your dismissView: to see if it gets called